# Is this resistor metal or carbon film?

Tags: resistors

[image]

My ceiling fan just stopped suddenly today, i took it apart and found a resistor had overheated and fused itself onto the plastic housing. I swapped the entire circuit board of another similar fan and it now works fine. But i needed to replace this faulty one and I thought a replacement of the resistor may do the trick. Thing is I can only tell its a 200 ohm 5% tolerance resistor. Anyone here can tell if its a metal or carbon film one? And the power rating?

Or if cant tell visually, its there anyway to measure them on a working model?

Thank you so much

Comment: Be aware that just because one resistor has overheated, does *not* mean that this is the only faulty component. In fact that overheating was likely caused by excessive current flow, because of a problem *somewhere else*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't measure the power rating of a resistor in the same way you can measure characteristics such as resistance.

I suggest you measure its physical size and find a new part with the right resistance and tolerance and physical dimensions as close as possible. Power rating of resistors tends to go pretty much hand in hand with physical size.

Based on the picture it's probably a 3W metal film part.